# How do I catch Uncaught TypeError fatal error?

Tags: php

I have a method that accepts arguments of type `string` but they also could be `null`. How can I catch this fatal error? 
`Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 5 passed to Employee::insertEmployee() must be of the type string, null given,` 
in the following code:

```
public function insertEmployee(string $first_name, string $middle_name, string $last_name, string $department, string $position, string $passport)
{
    if($first_name == null || $middle_name == null || $last_name == null || $department == null || $position == null || $passport == null) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Error: Please, check your input syntax.");
    }
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO employees (first_name, middle_name, last_name, department, position, passport_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->execute([$first_name, $middle_name, $last_name, $department, $position, $passport]);
    echo "New employee ".$first_name.' '.$middle_name.' '.$last_name.' saved.';
}


try {
    $app->insertEmployee($first_name, $middle_name, $last_name, $department, $position, $passport_id);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`TypeError`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php) extends [`Error`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) which implements [`Throwable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php). It's not an [`Exception`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php). So you need to catch either a `TypeError` or an `Error`:

```
try {
    $app->insertEmployee($first_name, $middle_name, $last_name, $department, $position, $passport_id);
} catch (TypeError $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks, but I want to display the following error message instead "Error: Please, check your input syntax." How can I catch this error? or is it not possible that the first error is before this one?

Comment: I think I just got what you wanted. Why are you doing that? You're essentially trying to bypass the language feature that's designed to do what you want, in order to do it yourself? The `TypeError` is being thrown specifically because a `string` was excepted and a `null` was given. So you don't need to check that by yourself, let the code handle it. You can just display the error message on the `catch` block.

Comment: Not stupid, just didn't know. We've all been there. We all *are* there :). Remember to read the manual! Good luck.