# phpUnit test code that sets up error handler

Tags: php, error-handling

I have some php code in a class that uses inheritance and requires and during that loading process, the error handler is setup. This interferes with my phpUnit test as it captures the exceptions/errors that phpUnit needs to run my tests. This is a large project and I can't just go change stuff. I can add stuff, though.

I cannot change the existing error handler code and as such I am looking for a way to make phpUnit be able to prevent the error handlers being called. I thought about overriding the call to set_error_handler, but this as expected gives the "cannot redeclare" error.

Currently I manually edit setup portion of the error handler by commenting the set_error_handler function call, but it would be nice if I could make this automatic without changing the source code (only changing the test code).

Is my problem clearly enough described?

Is what I need possible without adding runtime modules or changing the source code, i.e. just change the unittest php file?

Using php 5.5.

Comment: If it throwing an exception where it shouldn't, isn't that a problem?

Comment: I am making a unit test to ensure that a specific method has a certain type of argument. If I call with wrong argument type to trigger the error, php complains, and it must complain. I need the unit test to intercept the expected error. E.g. function foo(Bar $bar) called with "null".

Comment: That is not the same as an exception. You're looking to capture a [`TypeError`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46953864/5897602) or an `Error`.

Comment: I did write error handler (I also mentioned exception, though). The custom error handler captures too much and I cannot change that implementation. I was trying to work around it, but I don't know if it is possible. I guess I'll have to leave out that unit test.